# Solidity swap and add liquidity in contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, bsc, pancakeswap

I don’t understand what the error is, when you execute the `ZapInToken` function with a pair of `Cake/WBNB` or `Cake/USDT` tokens, everything is completed successfully.

If you take a pair with a commission of 5% (pancakeswap), it returns the error:

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). 
The transaction execution will likely fail.
Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted","id":2392006384191628}"
```

Despite the fact that the contract has the `SetFee` function and I set the required commission there.

[ZapV2.sol](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1stHPDy0_2lrEFccqfYnvkuvTq0yaDnpa?usp=sharing)

I tried to change the commission size using the `SetFee` function, approving everything was done, the number of tokens was also sufficient.